# Fetch User Details from Facebook and Twitter API using asp.net or javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am trying to fetch all the facebook and twitter users present inside a area (eg: Los Angeles).

I searched in Google found a link for facebook-

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

This is showing all the places present inside that lag and lat with 1000m displace from that area. This is not showing all the user present inside that area.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> This is showing all the places present inside that lag and lat with 1000m displace from that area. This is not showing all the user present inside that area

It's because you've used `type=place`

First of all, to query the users, you have to use `type=user`; BUT for what you are looking for-

> trying to fetch all the facebook users present inside a area

There's **no** way to do that using the facebook api. But you can do other things such as, searching the users by their names, for eg: `/search?q=sahil&type=user`

Comment: there is no method to get all the user present inside that lag and lat ??

Comment: My requirement:

a person wants the no of people present nearer to him.who are connected to fb or twitter.

how to solve this problem 

can you please suggest any solution so that i can overcome from this issue

Comment: Do you have any idea for twitter API??

is twitter API can server that one ?